# How can I submit my app if I didn't enrolled for the Apple Developer Program?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I made this app and I would like to put it in the App Store and I searched the Internet for how to do that but they all require you the account that you used to enrol for the Apple Developer Program and unfortunately I don't have one(I learned Swift by Youtube).
What can I do?
NOTE : I don't care if I have to pay any money.

Comment: It isn't really possible to put an app in the iOS App Store without a Developer Account. If you don't mind paying money (it is $99), why don't you simply create an account & submit your app?

Comment: @Scot Should I just enrol for the Apple Developer Program?Because when I tried , I got this : Sorry, you can’t enroll at this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way for you to distribute your app via the iOS App Store is to have it submitted by someone (or an organisation) that is enrolled with the Apple Developer Program. That *someone* doesn't necessarily have to be you, but based on your question that seems to be the best option.

You can refer to the [Enrollment](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/) page to get started, or skip straight to the [Start your enrollment](https://developer.apple.com/enroll/) page.

If you're getting the *Sorry, you can’t enroll at this time* message, you should also get a description below that as to why you can't enroll. If you don't, or the message doesn't make sense to you, then you can contact Apple Developer Program Support via this [form](https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit/).